# Open Recent Not Showing Recent Projects

Tags: interface

Pretty annoying,
I've reinstalled, but still the problem lingers.

Recent files is always empty in blender.

If I go to AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\config

It is keeping a log of recent files.

How do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Blender Preferences > Save & Load > Recent Files > 0

No idea why it was at 0... This was annoying.